# I want to redirect on login page when the session is expired in angular and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, session, uri, response.redirect

I have written code for session-tracking but also i want that after giving message"session time out." redirect to login page for re-login the application.

I expect the login page when session is expired,but the actual output is showing the same accessed page with no information after session expires instead of login page.

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.status(403).send("OOPS Session is timeout");
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
})
```

Comment: add some code you tryed

Comment: welcome to [so], would you mind sharing your code on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you? also go through how to create [mcve]

Comment: using guard would be good